# Representation of a linear map as a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, representation-theory

> Let $I = \left < f_1, \dots, f_n \right > \subset R$ be an ideal generated by homogeneous elements where $\deg(f_i) = d_i$ and $\phi$ be the graded $R$-mod homomorphism $$\phi: R(-d_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus R(-d_s) \to I$$ where $e_i \to f_i$. So it maps generators to $f_i$. If one treats $g = g_1e_1 + \dots + g_ne_n \in R(-d_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus R(-d_s) $ as a column vector $g = \begin{bmatrix}
>  g_1\\ 
> \vdots\\
> g_n
> \end{bmatrix}$ with $g_i \in R(-d_i)$, then why can we view $\phi$ as $$\phi(g) = \begin{bmatrix}
> f_1 & \cdots &f_n 
> \end{bmatrix} 
> \begin{bmatrix}
>  g_1\\ 
> \vdots\\
> g_n\end{bmatrix}.$$

I am not sure what it is asking. The map $\phi$ is a homomorphism, and it maps from vector space to vector space and is a linear map so it has a matrix representation. Is it just asking us to expand the matrix operation on the RHS of the given map ($f$ with $g$?)

Comment: It seems that a lot of information about $R$ is missing from this question. What are the $e_i$ for example?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, $e_i$ are the generators of $R(-d_i)$ and $R$ is a graded $R-$Module

Comment: What do you mean by "the" generators?

Comment: I just mean for notation.

Comment: That still does not make any sense to me. An $R$-module does not have any distinguished generator usually, so you need to specify one.

Comment: @jacobsmith In spite of the answer, I think there is something to check here: why $\phi(g)=g_1f_1+\cdots+g_nf_n$? (I know it's trivial, but it has to be done.)

Comment: @user26857, because $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Is there something I am missing...?

Comment: @user26857, do you just mean checking the homomorphism property? $\phi(g_1e_1 + \dots + g_ne_n) = g_1\phi(e_1) + \dots + g_n \phi(e_n)$?

Comment: @jacobsmith Actually I mean to use it in order to get $\phi(g)=g_1f_1+\cdots+g_nf_n$.

Comment: @user26857, sorry I am not following...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, there's basically nothing to check here.

Comment: This looks better as a comment.

Comment: I've never really liked the idea of answering a question in a comment for stylistic reasons, because then the system doesn't know that the question has been answered.